# Is it possible to put default folder path into showOpenDialog File Name text area at opening?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

When the `showOpenDialog` method is called, the address of the default folder path address does not automatically appear in the file name text area. The user has to choose a folder or file. However, I want to put the address of the default folder in the file name text area at starting. So the user should be able to select the default folder just by pressing the open button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZoWH.jpg)

Unfortunately, the `setCurrentDirectory` method only shows the files and folders under the relevant folder and the filename field is empty.

Comment: I suggest the code should instead adhere to the 'path of least surprise' for the user, and thus not futz about with this nonsense. The user will 'get it' if the chooser appears as it does by default.

Answer (score 1):

The closest what I think is possible what you want is the following:

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\Windows\\");
jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("Downloaded Program Files"));
BasicFileChooserUI ui = (BasicFileChooserUI) jFileChooser.getUI();
ui.setFileName("C:\\Windows\\Downloaded Program Files");
jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

I.e. you would rather show the parent folder and then chose the folder you want to to be selected. This doesn't show you the whole path, but from the user point of view I think it's what you wanted.

Edit: I added some solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you. But it is my second best solution. I need whole path if it is possible.

Comment: I edited my answer above. This should help you but I consider it a bit hacky. You should add an instanceof-check for this BasicFileChooserUI as it does not have to be one according to the API. If it's not, you have no chance to edit it with the normal API-accesses.